# Reading WCF JSON Serialization

Tags: wcf, json, serialization

I've recently tried to output JSON using the built-in WCF functionality rather than the JSON.net kit over at Newtonsoft.

I'm getting the JSON to output okay, but I'm still left behind some strange default Serialization markup left by WCF.

Here is what is outputted to the client doing a GET:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">{"LobbyID":2,"LobbyID2":0}</string>
```

I would like to be rid of the "xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" if possible, so it is just a straight JSON data type response.

Here is the lobby class with the relevant DataContracts:

```
[DataContract(Name = "LobbyContract", Namespace = "xx")]
public class Lobby
{
    [DataMember(Name="LobbyID")]
    private int LobbyID;

    [DataMember(Name = "LobbyID2")]
    private int LobbyID2;
```

and then I have this call functionality:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [Description("PlaceHolder")]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "xxx/xx/{gameID}/{format}") ]
    public string FindGameProposals(string gameID, string format)
    {

        Lobby lobby = new Lobby();
        lobby.SetLobbyID(Convert.ToInt32(gameID));

        string returnValue = "";
        if (format == "xml")
        {

        }

        else if (format == "json")
        {

            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(lobby.GetType());
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, lobby);

            // Return the results serialized as JSON
            string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            returnValue = json;



        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Obviously thanks for any advice or general direction I should be looking at, but I've gone through most examples and tutorials but alas they were to no avail.
It is a very simple test, whereby I perform the GET with a number, the service reads the number, assigns it to the class's ID variable, and then I read it, serialize it and send it back.

Comment: What specific problem are you having?  Which artifacts are you finding "strange" in the response?

Comment: Sorry I'll amend the post to make it clearer. I would like to have just straight JSON, without the "xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" if possible. Thanks for reading :)

Comment: I honestly have not seen that in my implementations. You may want to add the ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json to your WebGet definition however.

Comment: Hi Rocky thanks for the tip, it works to some extent using this, and I seem to have more convincing JSON as it has introduced some backslashes in the response and stripped out the xmlns part, however I was curious if there was a way I can adapt it to my needs. Which are to be able to specify which response format from the GET command from the client, e.g. the {format}, I don't really want to have to do two seperate methods, one for XML and one for JSON, just the ability to respond from one method. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: @Rodney: Without intercepting the request in an IDispatchMessageInspector implementation, you may be stuck with two methods. But, I have not completely thought it out. So, I will respond back later if I think of anything. Good luck!

Comment: At the moment I've decided to return a Stream and to just encode the message that way. It seems to be working so far, but I've yet to try and see if it will comply with the XML side of serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the BodyStyle to get rid of that...

```
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "xxx/xx/{gameID}/{format}"), BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to affect anything, I had some success with Rocky's post above.